# Deprecated PPAPI scripting plugins chrome

Tags: plugins, scripting, deprecated, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I need an example NaCl plugin with usage of scripting plugins with **deprecated** PPAPI (please, read below).

I have to develop a plugin using an old, deprecated scripting plugins from PPAPI (please, see http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/wiki/InterfacingWithJavaScript ). I need to call plugin methods from javascript in NPAPI/deprecated PPAPI way, like this:

```
plug = document.getElementByID("my_embedded_plugin");
result = plug.my_plugin_method();
```

The way of calling plugin methods from javascript is **mandatory** and I can't use PostMessage - HandleMessage methods for this task. Using PPAPI is **also** **mandatory**.

So I kindly ask for some **example NaCl plugins** (C and C++ sources and HTML files) using the **deprecated scripting plugins**, that I can compile, test and use as a model. Even if I have to modify and recompile chromium, please, provide me with such example, if you can.

Best regards,
Mario S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with current chrome. This way of writing PPAPI plugins is completely removed from chrome source. The latest version of chrome that supported that is around 12.

Here you can find some examples of using this scripting interface:
http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient-sdk/source/browse/?r=600#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fexamples